# Change order of tab bar items

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having a view which has a tab bar at the bottom. Now I want to change the items of the tab bar based on iPhone and iPad (i.e. different orders for iPhone and iPad).

In `viewDidLoad` if I do something like  `self.viewControllers.count`, I get the proper count of tab bars. But how to proceed from there in order to change the order of tab bar items I can't figure out. I mean how can I get the index of each of the viewcontrollers so that I can rearrange their indexes I can't figure out...

Comment: Viewcontroller is an array

Comment: yes @E.Coms `self.viewcontrollers` is predefined returning an array..

Comment: viewcontrollers is not readonly but mutable like this :  self.viewControllers?.sort{$0.view.tag < $1.view.tag } . setTag for the views of each bar item like [3,2,1,5,4,6]. Then call the above code, you can see they are changing orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your tab bar programmatically. but first, you should set an id for your tab views in storyboard like in image: 
[image: set id for view]

in `AppDelegate`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
// change "Main" if your storyboard's filename is different.

let vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1")
let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")

let tab = UITabBarController()
if UIDevice.current.model.lowercased() == "iphone" {
    tab.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
} else {
    tab.viewControllers = [vc2, vc1]
}

window?.rootViewController = tab
```

Comment: Thanks @p.yarandi. Actually I didn't want a swap. What I wanted was..if the initial order of tabbar items was [1,2,3,4,5,6], I want it as [1,3,5,2,4,6]

Comment: Welcome @user308123. you can do this by defining tab bar programmatically. Are you using storyboard for your ui?

Comment: yes..there is a storyboard which has a predefined list of tabbar items. but I want to change that order programatically while running...